# $ selector to get id

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

I have this :

```
<table>
@foreach(var foo in Model.List)
{
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" class="MnuCustomerSelect" id="@foo.Id">Select</a></td>
        <td>@foo.Id</td>
        <td>@foo.Code</td>
        <td>@foo.LastName</td>
        <td>@foo.FirstName</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

AS jQuery :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".MnuCustomerSelect").click(function () {

            var jqxhr = $.post("/Customer/Select", function (data) {
                $(this).Id();
            })
            .success(function () { })
            .error(function () { })
            .complete(function () { });

        });
    });
</script>
```

The question, I'd like when I click on the selected link, send the corresponding id as argument to /Customer/Select (will be used in my controller)

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do i easier:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".MnuCustomerSelect").click(function () {

        var jqxhr = $.post("/Customer/Select", {id: this.id}, function (data) {
            //do something with data
        })
        .success(function () { })
        .error(function () { })
        .complete(function () { });

    });
});
```

`this.id;` is native js to get the DOM id
and u send post elements as the 2nd var in the `$.post` call

Answer (score 1):

While you *can*, indeed, use `$(this).attr('id')` to retrieve the id, it's a little faster, and less work, to use the simple, and native to JavaScript, `this.id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.id` (*Thanks David*)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".MnuCustomerSelect").click(function () {

            var jqxhr = $.post("/Customer/Select",{ id: this.id }, function (data) {

            })
            .success(function () { alert('Success!'); })
            .error(function () { alert('Error!'); })
            .complete(function () { alert('Complete!'); });

        });
    });
</script>
```